# How to add the list items to a dictionary as value

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a Python dictionary as follows:

```py
{
    "ABC": "32066",
    "XYZ": "4413",
    "CCC": "4413",
    "DDD": "32064",
}
```

For the key `"ABC"` I have list `['wood', 'missi']`, if no value is present then we need to assign nulls.
The expected output as below:

```
{
    "ABC": ["32066", "wood", "missi"],
    "XYZ": ["4413", null],
    "CCC": ["4413", null],
    "DDD": ["32064", null],
}
```

Comment: Your expected output is invalid as a dictionary since each key must be unique.  Also, need commas between dictionary items.

Comment: a dictinary cannot has same key, and also it the has separated comma in each item

Comment: Thanks for letting me know i have changed my output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to edit dictionary values to consist a list of two items. First item is already the value itself, second one should come from a list. Whenever the list finishes giving item, you want to get `None`. You can use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
from pprint import pprint

d = {
    "ABC": "32066",
    "XYZ": "4413",
    "CCC": "4413",
    "DDD": "32064",
}
lst = ["wood", "missi"]


for (k, v), item in zip_longest(d.items(), lst, fillvalue=None):
    d[k] = [v, item]

pprint(d, sort_dicts=False)
```

output:

```
{'ABC': ['32066', 'wood'],
 'XYZ': ['4413', 'missi'],
 'CCC': ['4413', None],
 'DDD': ['32064', None]}
```

**Note1:** Remember you cannot have two identical keys in dictionary, next one will overwrite the previous one.

**Note2:** In Python we have `None`, not null.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know i have changed my output.